# R's pacman package, can it download dependencies too

Tags: r, package, pacman

Does **pacman**'s **p_load** have the option to download all **dependencies**?

I searched around the documentation but could not find an argument in the **p_load** function.

I guess I could list the dependencies via **p_depends** and the pass the results to **p_load**.

But I thought there must a better way than that.

Comment: Theoretically it should. Are you not getting that behavior?

Comment: Is it packages in imports or depends that aren't getting installed for you or is it the packages in suggests? It doesn't support installing the packages in suggest right now although we should change that. There was a discussion of this that is still open https://github.com/trinker/pacman/issues/43